# How can i move image on z-axis by using accelerometer?

Tags: iphone

My image is moving in tw0 directions. x and y axis, How can i move image in z direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-direction points towards you, so to say. Try accessing the layer of the view. It should have a z-parameter.